# second page won't display jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I upgraded my Android application from cordova-1.6.1 to cordova-2.5.0. Also, I upgraded from jquery.mobile-1.1.0 to jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js.  I'm runing my application on Android 2.3.3.  The first page, index.html is a splash screen, which after 3 seconds goes to a page login.html.  The first page, splash page, displays correct but the second page comes up blank, even if I link to another page off the first page.  This all worked before my upgrade(s).  I went one step further and copied all of my login.html page content to the index.html, and it displayed my login form correct.  Then whatever the next page is to be displayed it comes up blank.  Here is the code I'm working with:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>AFitnessPal</title>

        <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
        <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"  src="javascripts/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/DBAdapter.js"></script>


        </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="indexpage" data-dom-cache="false">

                <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                    <h1>AFitnessPal</h1>

                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <ul id="LoginForm" data-role="listview">
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="name">Login
                                ID:</label> <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="loginID" id="loginID"
                            value="" /></li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="name">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" maxlength="100" name="loginPassword"
                            id="loginPassword" value="" /></li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="slider2">Remember
                                login:</label> <select name="RememberLogin" id="RememberLogin"
                            data-role="slider">
                                <option value="0">No</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        </select></li>
                        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">

                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                    <button onclick="javascript:DoLogin();" data-theme="a">Submit</button>
                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                            <div align="center">
                                <a href="CreateAccount.html"> Create New Account</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
             function goToLogin()
             {
                 $.mobile.changePage("Login.html", { transition: "flip"} );

             }

              $("#indexpage").on('pageinit', function(){
                  alert('login.html pageinit fired');


                });

                $("#indexpage").on("pageshow", function(e) {
                    alert('login.html pageshow fired');

                  });


            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```